# Making JS Alert Look More Professional

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me make this alert look much nicer? Like Maybe split up Each text box on its own line? I can not figure out how to make this look a lot cleaner and not just all piled on one line.

To see alert hit Lien radio button and then hit next without filling textboxes

http://jsfiddle.net/t4Lgm0n2/9/

```js
function validateForm(){
 var QnoText = ['lien'];  // add IDs here for questions with optional text input
 var ids = '';
 flag = true;
 for (i=0; i<QnoText.length; i++) {
  CkStatus = document.getElementById(QnoText[i]).checked;
  ids = QnoText[i]+'lname';
        var eD = "";
  if (CkStatus && document.getElementById(ids).value == '') {
   eD = eD+' lienholder name';
   document.getElementById(ids).focus();
   flag = false;
  }
  ids2 = QnoText[i]+'laddress';
  if (CkStatus && document.getElementById(ids2).value == '') {
   eD=eD+' lienholder address';
   document.getElementById(ids2).focus();
   flag = false;
  }
  ids3 = 'datepicker2';
  if (CkStatus && document.getElementById(ids3).value == '') {
   eD=eD+' lien date';
   document.getElementById(ids3).focus();
   flag = false;
  }
        if(eD!="") alert("Please enter "+eD);
 }
  return flag;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="lien" id="lien" required="yes" onchange="showhideForm(this.value);"/><label for="lien">Lien</label>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="None" name="lien" id="nolien" onchange="showhideForm(this.value);"/><label for="nolien">No Lien</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showhideForm(lien) {
    if (lien == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
    } 
   else if (lien == "None") {
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';
  $("#div1 > .clearfix input:text").val("");
    }
}
</script>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
<div class="clearfix">
<label for="lname">Lienholder Name:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="lienlname" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" id="lienlname" size="54" maxlength="120" message="Please enter lienholder name." value="">
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for="laddress">Lienholder Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lienladdress" validateat="onSubmit" validate="maxlength" id="lienladdress" size="54" maxlength="120" message="Please enter lienholder address." value="">
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for="ldate">Date of Lien:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="lienldate" id="datepicker2" mask="99/99/9999" value="">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id="div2" style="display:none">
<!---You are not qualified to see this form.--->
</div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" onclick="validateForm()">
```

Comment: https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert

Comment: you cannot tweak the appearance of `alert()` as it is controlled by the browser. You'll need to use a javascript library like jquery UI to make it look how you want (or write your own).

Comment: http://akquinet.github.io/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/

Comment: Lol I am not trying to style it, You see how the alert is all on one line? I am trying to clean it up where it will show Please enter lienholder name.<br> Please enter lienholder address.<br>Please enter lien date.

Comment: but if only 1 is not filled out Please enter (only that one)

Comment: If 2 Please enter ... <br>Please enter ...

Comment: `alert('line one\nline two');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use new line characters `\n` to make text more readable:

```
var eD = [];

if (CkStatus && document.getElementById(ids).value == '') {
    eD.push('Please enter lienholder name');
    document.getElementById(ids).focus();
    flag = false;
}

// ...

if (eD.length) alert(eD.join('\n'));
```

As you can see I'm also pushing error messages into `ed` array, which makes it more convenient to concatenate resulting message using `.join()` method.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t4Lgm0n2/11/